# How to prevent shift when border is set?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have a web page, that looks as the following:

```css
.topbar-container {
  width: 100%;
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  background-color: #2d3e50;
  z-index: 999;
  display: flex;
  transition: height 500ms;
}

@media (min-width: 992px) {
  .topbar-container {
    height: 100px;
  }
}

@media (max-width: 991.98px) {
  .topbar-container {
    height: 80px;
  }
}

@media (min-width: 992px) {
  .navi-container {
    width: 100%;
    height: 50px;
    background-color: #01c2aa;
    position: fixed;
    top: 100px;
    z-index: 998;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    transition: top 400ms, width 400ms;
  }
  .navi-container .navi-menu {
    width: 992px;
    height: 100%;
    color: #2d3e50;
    display: inline-flex;
  }
  .navi-container .navi-menu a.navi-link {
    height: 100%;
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    overflow: hidden;
    position: relative;
    cursor: pointer;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    font-size: 1.4em;
    font-weight: 600;
    padding: 10px;
  }
  .navi-container .navi-menu a.navi-link-active {
    border-bottom: 3px #2d3e50 solid;
  }
}

@media (max-width: 991.98px) {
  .navi-container {
    width: 100%;
    background-color: #01c2aa;
    position: relative;
    top: 0px;
    z-index: 998;
    display: flex;
    transition: top 500ms;
    height: 50px;
  }
  .navi-container .navi-menu {
    width: 100%;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    padding-top: 80px;
    position: relative;
  }
  .navi-container .navi-menu a.navi-link {
    padding: 10px;
    padding-left: 20px;
    font-size: 1.2em;
    font-weight: 600;
  }
  .navi-container .navi-menu a.navi-link-active {
    box-sizing: border-box;
    border-left: 3px #2d3e50 solid;
  }
  .navi-show-on-mobile {
    height: 100%;
  }
}

.app-container {
  display: flex;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  flex-direction: column;
  top: 0px;
  position: relative;
  align-items: center;
}

* {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}

html,
body {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  font-size: 14px;
  font-family: 'Montserrat', sans-serif;
}

#root {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div id="root">
  <div class="app-container">
    <div class="topbar-container"></div>
    <div class="navi-container navi-show-on-mobile">
      <section class="navi-menu"><a class="navi-link">DASHBOARD</a><a class="navi-link navi-link-active">COINS</a></section>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

When you look as the full page:

[image]

The dashboard and coins navigation are not on the same line. How to achieve it?

Comment: Give the non-active item a transparent border.

Comment: Can you please provide an example

Comment: Is your question answered?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Give the non-active items a transparent border. For the active items, you then only need to change the border color.

```css
.topbar-container {
  width: 100%;
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  background-color: #2d3e50;
  z-index: 999;
  display: flex;
  transition: height 500ms;
}

@media (min-width: 992px) {
  .topbar-container {
    height: 100px;
  }
}

@media (max-width: 991.98px) {
  .topbar-container {
    height: 80px;
  }
}

@media (min-width: 992px) {
  .navi-container {
    width: 100%;
    height: 50px;
    background-color: #01c2aa;
    position: fixed;
    top: 100px;
    z-index: 998;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    transition: top 400ms, width 400ms;
  }
  .navi-container .navi-menu {
    width: 992px;
    height: 100%;
    color: #2d3e50;
    display: inline-flex;
  }
  .navi-container .navi-menu a.navi-link {
    height: 100%;
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    overflow: hidden;
    position: relative;
    cursor: pointer;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    font-size: 1.4em;
    font-weight: 600;
    padding: 10px;
    border-bottom: 3px transparent solid;
  }
  .navi-container .navi-menu a.navi-link-active {
    border-bottom-color: #2d3e50;
  }
}

@media (max-width: 991.98px) {
  .navi-container {
    width: 100%;
    background-color: #01c2aa;
    position: relative;
    top: 0px;
    z-index: 998;
    display: flex;
    transition: top 500ms;
    height: 50px;
  }
  .navi-container .navi-menu {
    width: 100%;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    padding-top: 80px;
    position: relative;
  }
  .navi-container .navi-menu a.navi-link {
    padding: 10px;
    padding-left: 20px;
    font-size: 1.2em;
    font-weight: 600;
  }
  .navi-container .navi-menu a.navi-link-active {
    box-sizing: border-box;
    border-left: 3px #2d3e50 solid;
  }
  .navi-show-on-mobile {
    height: 100%;
  }
}

.app-container {
  display: flex;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  flex-direction: column;
  top: 0px;
  position: relative;
  align-items: center;
}

* {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}

html,
body {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  font-size: 14px;
  font-family: 'Montserrat', sans-serif;
}

#root {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div id="root">
  <div class="app-container">
    <div class="topbar-container"></div>
    <div class="navi-container navi-show-on-mobile">
      <section class="navi-menu">
        <a class="navi-link">DASHBOARD</a><a class="navi-link navi-link-active">COINS</a>
      </section>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: @31piy In what regard? Maybe you missed OP stating *When you look as the full page*

Answer (score 1):

Add 3px transparent border in `.navi-container .navi-menu a.navi-link`

```css
.ripple {
  position: absolute;
  opacity: 0;
  border-radius: 50%;
  width: 2px;
  height: 2px;
  background-color: #ffffff;
  animation-duration: 1s;
  animation-name: ripple;
}

@keyframes ripple {
  0% {
    opacity: 0.4; }
  100% {
    transform: scale(165); } 
}

.topbar-container {
  width: 100%;
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  background-color: #2d3e50;
  z-index: 999;
  display: flex;
  transition: height 500ms; }
  @media (min-width: 992px) {
    .topbar-container {
      height: 100px; } }
  @media (max-width: 991.98px) {
    .topbar-container {
      height: 80px; } }

@media (min-width: 992px) {
  .navi-container {
    width: 100%;
    height: 50px;
    background-color: #01c2aa;
    position: fixed;
    top: 100px;
    z-index: 998;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    transition: top 400ms, width 400ms; }
    .navi-container .navi-menu {
      width: 992px;
      height: 100%;
      color: #2d3e50;
      display: inline-flex; }
      .navi-container .navi-menu a.navi-link {
        height: 100%;
        display: flex;
        align-items: center;
        overflow: hidden;
        position: relative;
        cursor: pointer;
        box-sizing: border-box;
        font-size: 1.4em;
        font-weight: 600;
        padding: 10px; }
      .navi-container .navi-menu a.navi-link-active {
        border-bottom: 3px #2d3e50 solid; } }

@media (max-width: 991.98px) {
  .navi-container {
    width: 100%;
    background-color: #01c2aa;
    position: relative;
    top: 0px;
    z-index: 998;
    display: flex;
    transition: top 500ms;
    height: 50px; }
    .navi-container .navi-menu {
      width: 100%;
      display: flex;
      flex-direction: column;
      padding-top: 80px;
      position: relative; }
      .navi-container .navi-menu a.navi-link {
        padding: 10px;
        padding-left: 20px;
        font-size: 1.2em;
        font-weight: 600;
        border-left: 3px solid transparent;
        }
      .navi-container .navi-menu a.navi-link-active {
        box-sizing: border-box;
        border-left: 3px #2d3e50 solid; }
  .navi-show-on-mobile {
    height: 100%; } }

.portfolio-container {
  width: 992px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 155px; }

.app-container {
  display: flex;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  flex-direction: column;
  top: 0px;
  position: relative;
  align-items: center; }

* {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0; }

html,
body {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  font-size: 14px;
  font-family: 'Montserrat', sans-serif; }

#root {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%; }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width,initial-scale=1,shrink-to-fit=no">
    <meta name="theme-color" content="#000000">
    <title>Cockpit</title>

<body cz-shortcut-listen="true">
    <noscript> You need to enable JavaScript to run this app. </noscript>
    <div id="root">
        <div class="app-container">
            <div class="topbar-container"></div>
            <div class="navi-container navi-show-on-mobile">
                <section class="navi-menu"><a class="navi-link">DASHBOARD</a><a class="navi-link navi-link-active">COINS</a></section>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>

</html>
```